# Certificate missing extensions

Tags: ssl, openssl

I'm using OpenSSL to generate keys/csrs/certs. I'm using a openssl.cnf file to add extensions to these certifications.

How do I check if a completed cert has the extensions that I requested using OpenSSL's command line?

I've tried this line of code:

```
openssl x509 -in certificate.crt -text -noout
```

But it doesn't show the extensions. I've also fiddled around with verify, but it doesn't work either.

I'm looking to check the values of these extensions: basicConstraints, keyUsage, serverAuth

Thanks

Comment: I believe you need v3 for extensions. Be sure you are not using v1 certificates. You may also need `copy_extensions = copy`. This can be dangerous, so use it with care. Can you show your code to create the certificate, and the relevant pieces of your `openssl.cnf`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> openssl x509 -in certificate.crt -text -noout
> ```
>
> But it doesn't show the extensions

If this does not show the extensions then there are probably no extensions in your certificate. If you take for instance the certificate you get when visiting paypal.com the command line above will give you lots of extensions, like:

```
    X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
            DNS:history.paypal.com, DNS:t.paypal.com, ...
        X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
            CA:FALSE
        X509v3 Key Usage: critical
            Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
        X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
            TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
    ...
```